# Crear hipervinculo a video desde itext para android

Tags: android, itext

Buenos días.

Desarrollando una app y haciendo uso de la librería itext para android, necesito que en el documento pdf generado aparezca la ruta de unos videos, y al clicar sobre ellos se abra el reproductor de video y los reproduzca.

Son videos almacenados localmente.

De momento en el pdf consigo que aparezca solo la ruta, pero lógicamente al clicar sobre ella no reproduce nada desde el pdf.

Este es mi trozo de código referente al problema:

```
      Font f6=new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN,15.0f, Font.BOLDITALIC|Font.UNDERLINE);
      Paragraph p6=new Paragraph("VIDEOS DE LA REUNIÓN:",f6);
      document.add(p6);
      document.add(new Paragraph(" "));


      for (File video:videos){


          document.add(new Paragraph(video.getAbsolutePath()));
          document.add(new Paragraph(" "));




      }
```

¿Se os ocurre alguna idea?

Answer (score 0):

Debe crear un `Anchor` y este agregarlo a tu documento:

```
Anchor mylink = new Anchor("Mis Videos!");
mylink.setReference("http://www.mydomain.coo/myVideo.mp4");
```

puedes agregarlo dentro del `paragraph`

```
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
paragraph.add(new Phrase("VIDEOS DE LA REUNIÓN:"));
paragraph.add(mylink);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Elena! el problema que el video se almacena de manera local, por lo que su ruta es algo asi:  storage/amulated/0/Reunuiones/nombreReunion/videos/video.mp4...